# How do I, modify vba code to repeat until finished?

Tags: excel, vba

I found a piece of vba code that counts the number of xml files in a specific folder, i modified it to only count files with a specific string (located in cell F3) as part of the file name. And print that count in the adjacent cell (cell G3). Its working as expected.
My problem is that I need the results for a entire range. The range of strings are created from a pivot table.

I tried just dublicating the code and modifying the reference cells, and that works. But the range can be from a few strings to 70+, i'm sure that there is a much more efficient and cleaner way than running the code 70+ times.

```
Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer

FolderPath = "C:\Test\PJC"
path = FolderPath & "\*" & Range("F3") & "*.xml"

FileName = Dir(path)

Do While FileName <> ""
   count = count + 1
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

Range("G3").Value = count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess this will do the trick.
I took your code and put it in a `For` loop.

I define the start row as row 3.

`EndRange` will search for the last value in column F. The For loop will iterate from `StartRange` to `EndRange` values.
I also made the count to print the the result from the count variable for each loop in the G column.

```
Sub LoopRange()


Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer
Dim StartRange As Long, EndRange As Long

StartRange = 3 'Row = 3 for start
EndRange = Cells(Rows.count, "F").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in column F

For i = StartRange To EndRange 'Loop from start to end value

    FolderPath = "C:\Test\PJC"
    path = FolderPath & "\*" & Range(Cells(i, "F"), Cells(i, "F")) & "*.xml" 'Take the value from row i and column F in the loop.

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
        count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Range(Cells(i, "G"), Cells(i, "G")).Value = count 'Print the count

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: This works, except it adds it keeps adding to the count for every file found. So file number 2 has a count of 2, if the first 2 files are present. If there are 2 of the first file and 1 of the next the second will have a count of 3. :)

Comment: Added Count = 0 before FolderPath and now it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a Range can be achieved as follows:

```
Sub IterateRange()

Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Dim myWs As Worksheet
Set myWs = Application.Worksheets("sheet1")

Set rng = myWs.Range("A1:A6")

For Each cell In rng
    MsgBox cell.Value
Next cell

End Sub
```

Often iterating might be more straightforward using the .Cells property of a Worksheet, it could look like this:

```
Sub IterateRange()

Dim i As Long
Dim myWs As Worksheet
Set myWs = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")

for i=1 to 6
    MsgBox myWs.Cells(i, 1)
next i

End Sub
```

For your example, if you have the strings you want to check for in the Range F3:F73, and the count results should be in the Range G3:G73 the loop you are looking for might look something like this:

```
Sub Example()

Dim FolderPath As String, path As String, count As Integer, i As Integer
Dim myWs As Worksheet
Set myWs = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For i = 3 To 73
count=0
    FolderPath = "C:\Test\PJC"
    path = FolderPath & "\*" & myWs.Cells(i, 6) & "*.xml"

    Filename = Dir(path)

    Do While Filename <> ""
       count = count + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    myWs.Cells(i, 7) = count
Next i

End Sub
```

For the loop to stop automatically after the last row of input strings just add

```
if myWs.Cells(i, 6)="" then
    exit for
end if
```

between the lines For i = 3 To 73 and count=0

Comment: I cant get this code working. It keeps going even when there is no string to count. And it keeps adding to the number of files found. As example i have 5 xml files in the folder. The result on line 73 was 468.

Comment: Of course i forgot resetting count sorry. I updated it! Also, i wrote the for loop to go to 73 just as example, you have to specify the upper bound of the for loop yourself. I will update the answer to include a version that finds the last row of strings on its own.

Comment: It counts correct now, except if there is no string. Then it counts all xml files in the folder.

Comment: I marked the reply from Wizhi as the correct answer. But got it working due to yours. So thanks a lot. :)

Comment: You are welcome. I edited it to include the statement to automatically stop once there is no input string at the end now.

Answer (score 1):

There you have alternatives:

```
    ' One line solution, but can count all files only, without wildcards
    Debug.Print CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder("C:\temp\").Files.count

    ' Counting all *.pdf files in C:\temp
    FolderPath = "\\temp\\"
    Path = "pdf"

    Dim objWMIService   As Object
    Dim objFiles        As Object

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set objFiles = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from CIM_DataFile where Path = '" & FolderPath & "' and Extension = '" & Path & "'")

    Debug.Print "Files count: ", objFiles.Count
```